# converting text files to csv with filename gives Error

Tags: python, csv, os.walk

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
filelocation = "C:\\test"
files= [k for k in next(os.walk(f"{filelocation}"))][2]
filenames = []
content=[]
for file in files:
    with open(f"{filelocation}\\{file}", 'r', newline='') as source_file:
        filenames.append(file)
        lines = source_file.read()
        content.append(lines)

data = {'Filename':filenames,
        'Content':content}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

df.to_csv(r'C:\\testing\\test.csv', index = False)
```

I'm having the following error when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    files= [k for k in next(os.walk(f"{filelocation}"))][2]
StopIteration
```

Comment: Did you want all of the files from a directory, or the directory and all of its child directories? `next(os.walk(f"{filelocation}")` isn't what you want... but the error suggests that there weren't any files in your target directory so that `next` raised StopIteration.

Comment: Remove pandas and crud tags, they are inapropriete for your problem.

Comment: Hello,

According to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration), StopIteration is raised when there is no items in generator - os.walk is returning that generator. Check filepaths, are they correct?

Comment: thanks for the reply, so I have the folder test and in that folder I have text files, I want to create a csv file to save in one column the name and in another column the content

Comment: I have managed to run it through Jupyter and it worked, but can please somebody help me as the first column saves as title.txt and I want it to be saved as only the name of the file without .txt, thanks